# How can I use the real crypto module in electron.js in the main process?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, electron

I'm writing a light wallet for a cryptocurrency with electron.js. Actually until now I just used pure node.js for the logic.Everything crypto related is handled in the main process of the electron.js app and I just figured out that crypto!=crypto && openssl != boringssl, so that some functions behave differently from the original node.js crypto module. This is now breaking my code.

So my question is now, how can I use the "original" crypto module from node.js with all dependent modules I'm using like create-hash in the electron main process?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, gladfully that the only problem was "rpmd160" which is a shortcut for "ripemd160" was working on node.js but not with electron.Just had to replace the shortcut with the full term and now everything is working.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? I'm having the same issue, and I need more guidance on how to fix this issue. Did you swap out an npm library to replace the ripemd160 module? If so, can you link to the library?

Answer (score 0):

I want to build on top of OP's answer as I was struggling with a very similar problem and his own answer lead me to a solution, but it wasn't clear at first how to solve.

### The Error

I was also trying to incorporate a cryptocurrency library into Electronjs, and was receiving this error:

```
[1] Could not start server. Error:  Error: Digest method not supported
[1]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
[1]     at createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
[1]     at ripemd160 (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/crypto.js:4:10)
[1]     at Object.hash160 (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/crypto.js:16:10)
[1]     at HDNode.getIdentifier (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/hdnode.js:133:18)
[1]     at HDNode.getFingerprint (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/hdnode.js:137:15)
[1]     at HDNode.derive (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/hdnode.js:277:31)
[1]     at HDNode.deriveHardened (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/hdnode.js:286:15)
[1]     at /home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/hdnode.js:311:21
[1]     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
[1]     at HDNode.derivePath (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/node_modules/@psf/bitcoincashjs-lib/src/hdnode.js:307:20)
[1]     at BchAdapter.generateBchId (/home/trout/work/psf/code/ipfs-coord/lib/adapters/bch-adapter.js:41:38)
[1]     at async ThisNodeUseCases.createSelf (/home/trout/work/psf/code/ipfs-coord/lib/use-cases/this-node-use-cases.js:65:21)
[1]     at async IpfsCoord.start (/home/trout/work/psf/code/ipfs-coord/index.js:93:21)
[1]     at async IpfsCoordAdapter.start (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/src/adapters/ipfs/ipfs-coord.js:81:5)
[1]     at async IPFS.start (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/src/adapters/ipfs/index.js:43:7)
[1]     at async Adapters.start (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/src/adapters/index.js:51:9)
[1]     at async Controllers.initAdapters (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/src/controllers/index.js:30:5)
[1]     at async Server.startServer (/home/trout/work/coinjoin/colab-coinjoin-api/bin/server.js:83:7)
```

The source of the error is that Electronjs replaces the Node.js native crypto modules, which comes from OpenSSL with the BorringSSL library from the Google Chromium team. [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25890) clued me in to this fact.

### The Fix

Looking at the error, it can be seen that ripemd160 is called out. Digging through my dependencies lead me to the [create-hash npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-hash). In my original code, I was calling this line:

- `return createHash('rmd160').update(buffer).digest()`

I was able to fix the problem by replacing `rmd160` with `ripemd160`, so that the line reads like this:

- `return createHash('ripemd160').update(buffer).digest()`

That's it! That one line change made the library work with BorringSSL in Electronjs.